# Tkinter add label in a child-label-frame inside a labelframe

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-entry, tkinter-layout

i am trying to create a label inside a labelframe -(inner) where the innerlabelframe is inside another labelframe -(outer)

```py
frame2 = LabelFrame(text='outer')
frame2.pack(side=LEFT,anchor=NW, expand=YES,fill='both',ipadx=10,ipady=0)
        
LabelFrameStops=LabelFrame(frame2,text='inner',padx=0,pady=0,width=100,height=100).pack(side=LEFT) #display correctly
Label(LabelFrameStops,text="one").pack() #need this inside the inner labelframe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a basic mistake, all the geometry managers return `None`, the variable `LabelFrameStops` holds the same. This should do it

```py
LabelFrameStops=LabelFrame(frame2,text='inner',width=100,height=100)
LabelFrameStops.pack(side=LEFT,padx=0,pady=0)
Label(LabelFrameStops,text="one").pack()
```

Comment: AST your answer worked but i m not sure with the explanation

Comment: @FaraiHuruba You had called `pack` on `Labelframe` and then stored that into `LabelFrameStops` which makes its value `None`. It was same as calling `Label(None,text="one").pack()` and so it assumed the parent as the root as opposed to the `Labelframe`.